# Консоль + окно, отдельное закрытие консоли

Tags: c++, c, winapi

С помощью функции `AllocConsole` вызываю консоль для своего оконного приложения. Осуществляю вывод, ввод, все хорошо. Далее, реализовал корректное закрытие всего приложения(т.е. окна и консоли) при нажатии на крестик окна. Теперь, хотелось бы узнать, как отдельно закрыть консоль не трогая основное окно(т.е. по нажатию на крестик консоли). Пробовал `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` ,но функция может только повесить оповещение на закрытие. Система все равно убивает процесс секунд через 6 - 7. Есть ли способы реализации данного действа? Спасибо.
P.S.: консоль обычно создаю в другом потоке, это для информации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызывайте [FreeConsole](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole), чтобы закрыть ее отдельно от основного окна.

Обработайте, например, какой-то код завершения в самой консоли, типа `close`, и вызывайте на него FreeConsole.

Comment: Была идея. Но невозможно обратиться именно к "крестику". Была также идея приаттачить специальную оконную процедуру к дескриптору консоли, обработать WM_QUIT, и в нем, перед посылом сигнала выхода вызвать FreeConsole. Но что-то меня остановила. буду пробовать, обязательно отпишусь.